# Moving Windows Mixed Reality main camera in Unity3D programatically

Tags: unity

I'm trying to programmatically move the main camera i.e. player's point of view/origin in a Windows Mixed Reality but for some reason it's not working for me (using newest latest stable Unity 2018 and HoloToolkit through which I've setup my WMR project)...
I've done the following:

```
m_MainCamera = Camera.main;
m_MainCamera.transform.position.Set(100f, 100f, 100f); 
UnityEngine.XR.InputTracking.Recenter();
```

if `(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))` happens, but even though the code gets run, my VR view position remains unchanged, and I'm guessing at 0,0,0 (or whatever is set initially)...so how exactly do they do those movements in the WMR's UI cliff house when you use the motion controller to point to place you want to transport your view...do they actually move all of the objects showing instead?

Or am I missing something really trivial when I can't move except for by moving my own body inside of VR? Maybe HoloToolkit is disabling it somehow... But how do I reenable it then to move to a predetermined places within a large life sized 3D model objects please?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

The camera’s local position and rotation are set by the VR input every frame. Not the world position, the local position. Just nest your camera in a parent GameObject and move that around instead.

Also, calling `Set` on the position won’t work the way you want it to. You need to assign a new value whenever you want to change it:

```
m_MainCamera = Camera.main;
//Move the camera’s parent to recenter the VR system (note: make sure the camera has a parent)
m_MainCamera.transform.parent.position = new Vector3(100f, 100f, 100f);
```